# Image with border radius and opacity on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, css

I'm working on a jquery plugin. I need to make mask effect over an image. Everything goes fine on FF but in Chrome and Opera doesnt work.

Here the html structure

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
</div>
```

and the css

```
#container, #container img { border-radius: 150em;}  
#container img:hover {opacity: 0.5; }
#container {
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #000;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
}
```

He're is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/geedmo/qQUfA/

Chrome looks fine until hover, but Opera works really bad.
Is anyway to achieve the mask effect without changing the html structure?

update: I need to crop the image

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems to work with opera 12.02

Comment: Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/qQUfA/5/

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qQUfA/4/ I had to add height and width for the image:

```
#container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it doesn't respect the image ratio

Comment: It's true. It rely on #container dimentions. Anyway it's possible to set necessary width and height instead of 100%.

Comment: basically I dont understand (too) why chrome doesnt crop the image on hover if the container has overflow:hidden... maybe a bug.